# AngularJS using $sce.trustAsHtml with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I'm trying to use $sce.trustAsHtml() with a property of an object in ng-repeat. The result is that the HTML is totally blank. The HTML outputs correctly using ngSanitize though.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(question.body)">
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm on AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.3 by the way. Not sure if there's a bug or I do something wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't use `$sce.trustAsHtml` in an expression (unless `$sce` is a property on the `$scope`) because expressions are evaluated in the context of the `$scope`.

The cleanest approach is to use `ngSanitize`.
The second cleanest is to expose `$sce.trustAsHtml` as a function in the `$scope`:

```
<div ng-repeat="...">
    <p ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(question.body)"></p>
</div>

$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Had trouble using $sce in services - worked only in filters and directives

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and it's short, simple and sweet. Thanks!

Comment: How about using `$sce.trustAsHtml(questions)` in controller and use only `<p ng-bind-html="question.body"></p>`. ?

Comment: @HardikMishra, that's also possible (and better than putting it in the template).

Answer (score 15):

OR have a filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(htmlCode){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
        }
}]);
```

in html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="question.body | sanitize"></div>
```

Comment: It does not sanitize htmlCode for me