# Angular.js + PHP: angular expression not executed if inside a ngSanitized html template

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

i'm trying to accomplish something really nice (and really strange).

I've got an angular controller calling (with $http.get, passing arguments got from angular) a php script which 
gets some data from the database and decide to echo one out of two possible html templates.

The problem is, in those templates there are expressions which should be parsed by angular. They don't.

Here are the scripts:

the first angular controller:

```
    $http.get("../php/jwtCheck.php?token=" + localStorage.token + "&courseid=" + $stateParams.id).success(function (response) { 

       $scope.phpData = $sce.trustAsHtml(response);

    });
```

the receiving php script:

```
//doing mysql stuff
if (sqlStuff::isBought($row[bought], $stuffID)){
                include '../boughtTemplate.html';
            } else
            {
                include "../previewTemplate.html";
            }
```

inside the templates i have this call to angular $scope:

```
<video data-html5-video="{{generateVideoFolder($index)}}" data-controls="true" data-preload="false" data-width="400" data-height="224">
</video>
```

which never got parsed by angular.

Any idea?

Comment: Read [Debugging AngularJS Apps](http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-console/)

Comment: I'd check the responses of the php script and how Angular is receiving them first

Comment: @KhaledShaaban the $scope.phpData should be injected in the main template like this:
 `<div ng-bind-html="phpData"> </div>`
but it doesn't

Comment: see [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459613/5390414) , hope it helps you out somehow

Comment: @KhaledShaaban not really helping. I'm already using ngSanitize in the right way (just checked). The real problem is I have to make Angular parse an expression inside the content of a ngSanitized string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile `phpData`.

Here is one approach I stole from another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994559/3563439

See the solution applied to your case in my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/zfftw7qr/

Comment: really easy and really smart. Thank you a lot!