# Convert JSON HTML string to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have developed an AngularJS Moodle webapp using Moodle WebService and I'm triying to show a quiz from Moodle eLearning.

I can get every question using `$http.`. now the problem is that when I get the question, every question comes with a HTML code like this:

[image: JSON Response]

An I'm using this controlores to get the **response (url5)**

```
app.controller('quizCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

url4 = concatUrl + 'mod_quiz_start_attempt' + '&quizid=2'; 

$http.get(url4).then(function (response) {
                    //console.log(response.data); 
                })

url5 = concatUrl + 'mod_quiz_get_attempt_data' + '&attemptid=7&page=0'; 

$http.get(url5).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.questions = response.data.questions;
                })
})
```

When I show the question in my HTML using the following code, I'm getting HTML code as a string and tried to used `ng-bind-html` but I got an error.

```
<div role="main" id="main" class="ui-content scroll" ng-app="mainApp">
<div data-role="content" class="pane" id="">
    <div class="page-wrap scroll" ng-controller="quizCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy : 'question.number'" id="{{question.number}}">
            <div>
                <!--{{question.html}}<br /><br />-->
                <p ng-bind-html="question.html"> </p><br /><br /> 
            </div>
          </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Error]

Also, I tried with:

```
JSON.stringify
angular.fromJson(json);
```

When I use this lines `{{question.html}}<br /><br />`, I'm getting this:

[image: With regular line]

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: If you use 'angular.js' instead of 'angular.min.js' you will see error texts, instead of links. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the *Strict Contextual Escaping Service* (`$sce`).
This is a service that enables you to specify the contexts in which it is O.K. to allow arbitrary HTML.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Inject it in your controller:

```
app.controller('quizCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $sce) 
...
$http.get(url5).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $sce.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml; // <- needs to be exposed on $scope
    $scope.questions = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.questions);
})
...
```

And in your view:

```
{{questions}}
```

Comment: O.K. Referred to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459194/angularjs-using-sce-trustashtml-with-ng-repeat, which explains how to solve that issue. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: I have to use this filter `.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(htmlCode){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
        }
}])` Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, creating a filter is one way. Essentially, you can't use `$sce.trustAsHtml` inside an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$sce` service

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(varWithHTML)
```

to make binding html work.

As the docs says https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: I tried with an specific varaible like `$scope.questions2 = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.questions[0].html)` but if you tried with `, `$scope.questions = response.data.questions`, ng-repeat` doesn't work.